# How does this binary tree code works in java?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I have been studying data structures these days, but I have some issues with understanding how recursion works. Can someone please tell me how does this piece of code work.

```
public static int height(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root){
    if (root==null)
        return 0;
    
    int left=height(root.left),right=height(root.right);
    if(left>right)
        return left+1;
    else 
        return right+1;
```

Comment: Using a debugger and stepping through the code may help you understand better than us trying to explain it to you in words. Also, binary trees are taught by pretty much any CS undergraduate degree and so there's probably a lot of tutorials, videos, animations, and so on out there.

Answer (score 0):

So, the algorithm goes to the leaf nodes, when it reaches the null node, then it returns 0, and recursion starts going from down to up. Because we want to get the max depth of the tree, we must compare the depth of left and right branches. And for every next level of the tree, we should increase the depth by one.

The extra materials about this theme [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MARxXuqnVGw), [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_-h_mpDmeg&t=382s) and [three](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-data-structure/)